# xlwings set alignments with api reference to pywin32

Tags: python, xlwings

I am trying to align text in a cell inside of an excel file that was created with xlwings. I am aware that there isn't a top level function in xlwings to achieve that. However, in the documentation, it states that .api can be used to access the pywin32 (on windows) to achieve that goal and in the documentation for pywin32 there is a method called SetTextAlign.

My problem is that I cannot figure out how to call it or what arguments to pass into it. A good bit of info can be found here: http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/PyCDC__SetTextAlign_meth.html
but that only helps me a tiny bit.

So, for example, my code could be:

```
self.sheet['A1'].value = 'test'
self.sheet['A1'].font.api ... # code here to set the alignment to center
```

Would be super appreciated if someone could help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.sheet['A1'].api.HorizontalAlignment = xlwings.constants.HAlign.xlHAlignCenter
```

Alignment is not a font property, but a Range property. A cell ('A1') is a Range.

You can find the Excel API [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/excel/object-model).

The PyCDC documentation you found is some internal Windows API, it is irrelevant for Excel features.

Comment: thank you so much, it works really well. I looked through the excel api, though, and I am still confused as to how to read it. For example, I tried setting a border this way and found BorderStyle, BorderColor, Border etc. but when I tried to use it with .api it always threw an error. Also, is there a list for the different constants?  Thank you so much again :)

Comment: It's a complex program, and xlwings tries to trade simplicity vs. completeness. Several .api properties in xlwings will give you Application, Workbook, Worksheet or Range objects. For borders start with documentation of the Range object, see it's Borders property which returns a Borders object, which has properties to format all range borders at once plus the Item property which let you select specific borders. Constants should be linked where needed, e. g. Borders.Item links to the constants in xlBordersIndex. There is also a link "Enumerations" in the docs.